# Validating HMAC-SHA256 signature in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, authentication, hmac

I am trying to validate HMAC-SHA256 signature against Node.js server with a simple Python client which validates against Python server. For some reason, I am unable to properly validate it in Node.

```
##
# client.py
##
import json
import time
from urllib import error
from urllib import request
import hmac
from hashlib import sha256

USER = 'testuser'
KEY = 'xxwMXEqOGiY2TssVZ9hvOB4x6EVW3RW75hjAKEai4UBlxG0ts8Js8dsWOzDvAVq4'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    now = int(time.time())

    payload = {'firstname': 'john', 'lastname': 'doe'}
    payload_json = json.dumps(payload)
    payload_bytes = bytes(payload_json, 'utf-8')

    sig = hmac.new(bytes(KEY, 'utf-8'), b'', sha256)
    sig.update(bytes(str(now), 'utf-8'))
    sig.update(payload_bytes)
    signature = sig.hexdigest()

    headers = {
        'Authorization': '{}:{}'.format(USER, signature),
        'timestamp': str(now),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    req = request.Request('http://localhost:8080/', payload_bytes, headers, method='POST')
    try:
        with request.urlopen(req) as response:
            response_code, response_reason, r = response.code, response.reason, response.read()
    except error.HTTPError as e:
        response_code, response_reason, r = e.code, e.reason, e

    print('RESPONSE: {} {}\n{}'.format(response_code, response_reason, r))
```

In Python, I validate the request (successfully) like this:

```
##
# snippet from server.py
##
user = {'user': 'testuser', 'secret_key': 'xx...'}  # usually queries the database
if user:
    check_sig = hmac.new(bytes(user['secret_key'], 'utf8'), b'', sha256)
    check_sig.update(bytes(headers['TIMESTAMP'], 'utf-8'))  # timestamp sent in request header
    check_sig.update(data)  # data is binary json-formatted string
    check_signature = check_sig.hexdigest()

    if hmac.compare_digest(check_signature, hmac_hash):  # hmac_hash is user's signature from request
        time_diff = int(time.time()) - int(headers['TIMESTAMP'])
        if 0 <= time_diff <= 30:
            print('kewl!')
            return True
```

In Node, I tried to use [node-restify](http://restify.com/) and have a simple code like this:

```
/*
* server.js
*/
var restify = require('restify');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var bufferEq = require('buffer-equal-constant-time');
var _ = require('lodash');
var nconf = require('nconf').file({file: 'config.json'});


var server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
// server.use(require(path.join(__dirname, 'auth'))());
server.use(restify.dateParser());
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.jsonp());
server.use(restify.gzipResponse());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
// server.use(restify.requestExpiry());
server.use(restify.throttle({
    burst: 100,
    rate: 50,
    ip: true,
    overrides: {
        '192.168.1.1': {
            rate: 0,        // unlimited
            burst: 0
        }
    }
}));
server.use(restify.conditionalRequest());


server.use(function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    console.log('checking auth...');

    var user = req.headers.authorization.split(':')[0];
    var key = req.headers.authorization.split(':')[1];
    console.log(key);

    var credentials = nconf.get('Security:Users');
    var dbUser = _.filter(credentials, {user: user}).pop();

    var checkSignature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', dbUser.key)
        .update(req.headers.timestamp, 'utf8')
        .update(JSON.stringify(req.body), 'utf8')
        .digest('hex');

    console.log(checkSignature);
    if (!bufferEq(new Buffer(checkSignature), new Buffer(key))) {
        return next(new restify.UnauthorizedError('Authorization error.'));
    }

    return next();
});


function respond(req, res, next) {
    res.send('hello!');
    next();
}

server.get('/', respond);
server.post('/', respond);

server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

...but comparing signatures always fails.

Is this the correct way to create HMAC-SHA256 signature in Node? I was following [crypto's documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hmac) and it seems pretty straightforward...

Comment: Could you post the output of both end results of the signature?

Comment: @GiveMeAllYourCats Well, since HMAC is generated with the current timestamp i can just provide you with bunch of SHA256 strings which in Python would be identical and in Node.js are always different :) Technically, in Python I receive 200 OK response and in Node 401 UNAUTHORIZED. If you think that printing out/logging some other stuff I receive in request or whatever else would be of any help I will be glad to share it with you, just let me know what exactly do you need ;)

Comment: ok the reason i'm wanting the output is encoding. Did you notice anything strange?

Comment: @GiveMeAllYourCats On Python's client side I am sending utf-8 encoded bytestring and in Python server (as `data` in my example) receiving exactly the same type and structure. On Node server, `req.body` is received as JS object, which I later convert to string (`JSON.stringify(req.body)`) and even forcing utf-8 encoding. I tried to change the `Buffer` comparison on Node side but the thing is that it will always fail since re-generated signature is never the same as the one user sent (both are SHA256 strings, but they just don't match :))

Comment: @GiveMeAllYourCats for example, in last run, the signature client sent was `4f8e40a4bf5eb06565e135ad26d1eb430a21575978fba4ed6a6905b66d307d51` and regenerated one on Node server was `64fe27f45822a8ad3287f7399ba2ff92d5002dbd5b0c95172ab08c49750a54d0`...